# Why does the IDE give a warning when I try to call the constructor from a member function?

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

I'm trying to take a object by reference to a member function as an argument and assign it to a new object, the IDE gives me a warning says that I should avoid using unnamed objects with custom construction and destruction. So I was asking about an alternative for doing so, or to understand what does the warning mean.

I'm using C++17, The program works fine and all is well, but I just don't know an alternative to do in order to get rid of the warning.

The actual warning message: `Warning    C26444  Avoid unnamed objects with custom construction and destruction (es.84). Project2    c:\xx\repos\project2\project2\big_int.cpp   304`

```cpp
void big_int::copyInto(big_int& b) {
    b = big_int{this->data}; // this->data is string
}
```

Suppose that there's a constructor for the class `big_int` that takes a `string`, this line gives me the mentioned warning.

p.s.: I know that this is exactly the job of the copy constructor itself, but I was just giving an example to elaborate my problem.

Comment: I would do `b = *this;` and let the assignment operator do it's job.

Comment: @mch Have you read the last note? That's not what I was doing. It's just for elaboration.

Comment: @drescherjm Thank you, I added it to the question!

Comment: I don't understand why anyone would recommend the advice in that message.

Comment: I am not talking about the copy constructor `bigint(const bigint & );`, but about the assignment operator `bigint & operator=(const bigint &);`

Comment: Do you use rule of zero? Are you using `std::vector` for `data` field? You should!

Comment: This seems like a bug in Visual C++ - according to the documentation, it looks like it should not warn about this situation.

Comment: Which is the signature of `operator =`? Does it return `big_int` value?

Comment: @MarekR I'm using  the rule of zero my copy and assignment constructions are assigned `= default`. And I'm using an std::string for it, does this seem wrong?

Comment: @molbdnilo I'm leaving it `= default`, returns a `big_int&`

Comment: @mch Yeah, I got your point, but the situation is that the class is not only made of the std::string `data` member, I want to use this exact constructor.

Comment: If you using `assignment constructions are assigned = default` it is not rule of zero. As a result your move constructor and move assignment has been disabled.

Comment: @MarekR isn't the `=default` only requesting the compiler to construct them?

Comment: forget about it I was wrong: https://wandbox.org/permlink/QApNefqe0M7QzIME

Comment: @MarekR Thank you, I didn't know about `is_move_constructible_v` and `is_move_assignable_v`, I checked them for my class and they gave back true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nitpick: this is not calling the constructor. It is impossible to directly do so. The syntax looks like it, but there is no syntax to do it.

What you're really doing is creating a *temporary* of type `big_int`, and assigning it to `b`.

And I cannot think of anything wrong with that. Strange warning.

You can work around it by hoisting the new object into a named variable then *move*-assigning it, but that code is more verbose and IMO entirely unnecessary. (And I *think* it prohibits guaranteed elision? Not sure that's relevant with this particular example but hey.)

I'd just disable the warning.

Answer (score 0):

> Avoid unnamed objects [..]

So name it:

```
void big_int::copyInto(big_int& b) {
    auto temp = big_int{this->data}; // this->data is string
    b = std::move(temp);
}
```

or disable the warning explicitly

```
void big_int::copyInto(big_int& b) {
#pragma warning (push)
#pragma warning (disable : 26444) // Avoid unnamed objects with custom construction and destruction
    b = big_int{this->data}; // this->data is string
#pragma warning (pop)
}
```